# Does not load for loop data in the dynamically created fields

Tags: javascript, html

I can see the list of components normally but when I use the "Add more" functionality it refuses to load the data. Any idea why?

*Normal select which loads data from for loop (HTML page)*:

```
<select name="component" data-live-search="true" id="component" class="form-control" title="Dropdown field">
         {% for i in component %} 
         <option value="{{i.id}}">{{i.name}}</option>
         {% endfor %}
```

(Inspect page)

```
<select name="component" data-live-search="true" id="component" class="form-control" title="Dropdown field">
          
         <option value="2">test2</option>
          
         <option value="3">sdf</option>
          
         <option value="4">qwerty</option>
          
         <option value="5">qwerty</option>
          
         <option value="6">example</option>
</select>
```

Now I'm dynamically creating fields using createElement and setAttribute

(HTML page)

```
var field = document.createElement('select');
field.setAttribute('name','component');
field.setAttribute('data-live-search','true');
field.setAttribute('id','component');
field.setAttribute('class','form-control');
field.setAttribute('title','Dropdown field');
survey_options.appendChild(field);
```

But this does not contain the data from the for loop similar to the normal select function. Am I missing something?

(Inspect page)

```
<select name="component" data-live-search="true" id="component" class="form-control" title="Dropdown field"></select>
```

Comment: If you are using EJS templating engine, I see you are using `for..in` instead of `for..of` loop

Comment: Must take care to have different `id` for the newly created elements. This snippet adds the options to dynamically created elements `field.innerHTML = document.querySelector('#component').innerHTML;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create dynamic element with different `id` and append the options from rendered element. Check the below snippet

```js
function appendNewDynamicComponent() {
    var survey_options = document.querySelector("#survey_options");
    var field = document.createElement('select');
    // Create a random number
    var random = +(Math.random() * 1e5).toFixed(0) + Date.now();
    field.setAttribute('name', 'component');
    field.setAttribute('data-live-search', 'true');
    // Append random number to id to make it unique for newly created element
    field.setAttribute('id', 'component_' + random);
    field.setAttribute('class', 'form-control');
    field.setAttribute('title', 'Dropdown field');
    survey_options.appendChild(field);

    // Below two lines would update the options for dynamicay created elements from the already rendered element
    field.innerHTML = document.querySelector('select#component').innerHTML;
    field.selectedIndex = -1;
}
```

```css
#survey_options [name="component"] {
  margin: 8px;
}
```

```html
<div id="survey_options">
    <select name="component" data-live-search="true" id="component" class="form-control" title="Dropdown field">
        <option value="2">test2</option>
        <option value="3">sdf</option>
        <option value="4">qwerty</option>
        <option value="5">qwerty</option>
        <option value="6">example</option>
    </select>
</div>
<br/>
<button onclick="appendNewDynamicComponent()">
    Add Dynamic Component
</button>
```

Comment: This is a bit confusing. How would creating dynamic element with different id help? As it is just creating a new attribute "id". I need to display values from a for loop in the dynamically created select element.

Comment: @Neil, unique `id` per element is HTML standard. To append the options, the last two lines of code is sufficient, Making different `id` helps the snippet `document.querySelector('select#component').innerHTML` to pick options from correct element with options from for loop.

Comment: It just prints this without option values ```<select name="component" data-live-search="true" id="component_1667400869077" class="form-control" title="Dropdown field"></select>```

Comment: @Neil Check out the updated answer with demo

Comment: this works perfectly. Do you any way through which I can multiselect in the dynamic field? Normally, I use the class="form-control selectpicker" to multiselect but that does not work in the dynamically created elements